# Is it possible to get rid of ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 using Support Test Library?

Tags: android, junit4, android-support-library, android-testing

I'm trying to use `Android Support Test Library` (previously [android-test-kit](https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/)) and create tests for one of my projects. It contains some 'functional' code along with UI code in single project.

My intention is to use JUnit4 and not mix with JUnit3, so I use [AndroidJUnitRunner](https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/wiki/AndroidJUnitRunnerUserGuide).
There's number of test classes created for the 'functional' code which follow JUnit4 and work fine.

Recently I've started to implement tests for UI components. Referring [documentation receipt](https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/wiki/AndroidJUnitRunnerUserGuide#Backwards_compatibility_to_Android_platform_testing_APIs) number of tests have been implemented. These activity tests follow JUnit4 style and extend `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2` based on above doc.

The problem that I'm facing now: it's not possible to execute all tests at once. If I try to run package / all tests (Activity and 'functional' are presented in the same project) from IntelliJ Idea - only pure JUnit4 tests get executed. I suspect that the problem is in `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2` which extends `TestCase` and is not pure JUnit4 test class.

Is it possible somehow to get rid of ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 in Activity tests using Android Support Test Library (android-test-kit) and have all test running? Or my assumption about the issues rootcause (about `TestCase`) is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found only possible solution: copy `InstrumentationTestCase`, `ActivityTestCase` and `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2` into my project from AOSP source. After that, remove inheritance from `InstrumentationTestCase` of `TestCase`. Same way it's done in this project ([AndroidJunit4](https://github.com/esmasui/AndroidJUnit4)).
There's actually no need for `TestCase` and these changes and [documentation receipt](https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/wiki/AndroidJUnitRunnerUserGuide#Backwards_compatibility_to_Android_platform_testing_APIs) are enough to have activity tests to be JUnit4 and avoid mixing issues.

Answer (score 3):

`InstrumentationTestCase`, `ActivityTestCase` and `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2` are deprecated, you should be using [ActivityTestRule](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/rule/ActivityTestRule.html) instead. [InstrumentationRegistry](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/InstrumentationRegistry.html) is also useful to get a hold of application context and instrumentation instances.

Comment: Why it's deprecated? Not able to see any deprecation mention under ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 reference. Looks like ActivityTestRule is a new thing, will check it out. I'm actually using InstrumentationRegistry in lot of places.

Comment: The deprecated APIs are tied to the platform so you might see them deprecated in the next Android platform release.